# Is a file name with its file extension (without the path) considered a URL?

Tags: html, url, filenames, file-extension, relative-url

I was wondering if `index.html` is a relative URL or not.

I know that `Website/Pages/index.html` is a URL. But what if it was just the file name and file extension without the path? Would it still be called a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What a path relative URL is](http://www.w3.org/TR/url-1/#concept-path-relative-url)

And, **yes**, `index.html` can be a relative url.

> When referring to a file that occurs in the same directory as the referring page, a URL can be as simple as the name of the file

If you want to link to your `index.html` page from your `about.html` page, as long as they're in the same directory you could very simply do:

```
<a href="index.html">Index</a>
```

What i think you are confusing is absolute vs relative paths. As other's are describing, a URL with an ***absolute path*** needs to be defined by:

1. protocol: (http://)
2. domain: (bobsjingles.)
3. extension: (edu)
4. directory path: (/journeycovers)
5. fragment: (/index.html)

`http://bobsjingles.edu/journeycovers/index.html`

All that absolute path does (essentially) is point to an IP / port on a machine, where you can send a request under a specific protocol (http), and get an expected data result (html.)

Answer (score 2):

Both of your examples are relative paths, not urls.

**Relative url examples:**

```
<A href="suppliers.html">Suppliers</A>
<IMG src="../icons/logo.gif" alt="logo">
<IMG src="image/logo.gif" alt="logo">
```

> A relative URL (defined in [[RFC1808]](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/references.html#ref-RFC1808)) doesn't contain any protocol or
>   machine information. Its path generally refers to a resource on the
>   same machine as the current document. Relative URLs may contain
>   relative path components (".." means one level up in the hierarchy
>   defined by the path), and may contain fragment identifiers.

SRC: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html

---

**URL Definition:**

> URL is an acronym for Uniform Resource Locator and is a reference (an
>   address) to a resource on the Internet. A URL has two main components:
>   Protocol identifier: For the URL http://example.com , the protocol
>   identifier is http . Resource name: For the URL http://example.com ,
>   the resource name is example.com.

SRC: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/definition.html (this is a url)

---

**Absolute path**:

```
/home/you/index.html
```

---

**Relative path:**

```
you/index.html
index.html
```

> Absolute and relative paths
>
> An absolute or full path points to the same location in a file system
>   regardless of the current working directory. To do that, it must
>   contain the root directory.
>
> By contrast, a relative path starts from some given working directory,
>   avoiding the need to provide the full absolute path. A filename can be
>   considered as a relative path based at the current working directory.
>   If the working directory is not the file's parent directory, a file
>   not found error will result if the file is addressed by its name.

SRC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

In a HTTP URL like `http://example.com/index.html`, `/index.html` *is* the URL’s path.

HTTP URLs don’t "know" or care about file names or file extensions.

There is no conceptual difference between paths like `/index.html`, `/index_html`, `/index`, `/index/foo/html`, or `/foooo`. (Servers, on the other hand, might use various conventions, like appending a dot followed by a file extension, to do *something* if such a URL is requested.)

Answer (score -1):

[URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/definition.html) is an acronym for Uniform Resource Locator and is a reference (an address) to a resource on the Internet.

Having said that, a file name with its extension is not a URL as it is not enough to determine the location of the file on the internet.

However, a file name and its extension can be referred to as a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier).

URI can be a locator (http://example.com) or a filename (example.txt) and the combination of both is the URL (and can still be called a URI).

Here is the complete [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for your reference.

[Read this article](https://danielmiessler.com/study/url_vs_uri/) to help you understand more the difference between URIs and URLs along with some examples